# What happens to the scheduled jobs in which its class is deleted in the updated app version

Tags: android, jobservice, gcmtaskservice

Let's say I use a JobService on my current app version. Then in the next app version, I want to delete the JobService class because I no longer need it. Is is safe to do so or do I need to take a phased approach where I keep the JobService class and explicitly cancel the job for some time?

I would like to ask the same about GCMTaskService.

This post got me concerned about it. I would like to know if it's a real concern.
Ref: [How to Remove an unused GcmTaskService service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878703/how-to-remove-an-unused-gcmtaskservice-service)

Comment: What approach did you take? Did you just cancel your previous jobs?